# H2 throwing exception running junits in Java 1.7, works in 1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, h2

We are just updating to run on 1.7 and encountered this error for junit testing

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.apache.openjpa.persistence.meta.AnnotationProcessor6' less than -source '1.7'
1 warning
```

while compiling this:

```
CREATE alias TO_DATE AS $$
java.util.Date toDate(String d, String p) throws Exception {
p = p.replaceAll("Y","y").replaceAll("m","M");
return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(p).parse(d);
}
$$;

H2/openjpa version:
<openjpa.version>2.3.0</openjpa.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.178</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I found that it is throwing exception here:

org.h2.util.SourceCompiler:

```
private static void throwSyntaxError(String err) {
if (err.startsWith("Note:")) {
// unchecked or unsafe operations - just a warning
    } else if (err.length() > 0) {
        err = StringUtils.replaceAll(err, COMPILE_DIR, "");
        throw DbException.get(ErrorCode.SYNTAX_ERROR_1, err);
    }
}
```

The message starts with "warning" and not "Note", thus exception thrown.
My eclipse.ini is pointing 1.7. Project is compiled in 1.7 too.
What is causing the warning message?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since the package that is failing is an `org.apache` package, my guess is that you need to get a more recent ( > 1.7) version of the apache library you are referencing.

Comment: The root cause of the problem might be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2300 - a workaround would be to extend the `throwSyntaxError` in H2 to ignore the warning (well, all warnings actually).